# Expression in Prometheus to determine constant growth over time

Tags: prometheus, grafana, activemq-artemis, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

We get metrics about the number of messages in queues from our instance of ActiveMQ Artemis 2.10.0 to Prometheus, and I need to be notified when for a certain amount of time (let's say 8 hours) the queue grows and does not decrease (usually this indicates a problem with the service that pulls messages from queues).

Like this:

[image]

But if I see something like this in the image below i.e. peak growth followed by a decrease, then the alert should not be triggered:

[image]

Now I use this expression, but sometimes it does not work correctly due to large growth spurts even with a subsequent decrease:

```
floor((predict_linear(artemis_message_count{job="activemq",queue=~".*"}[24h], 3600 * 24 * 1))) - max_over_time(artemis_message_count{job="activemq",queue=~".*"}[24h]) > 0
```

Can't figure out which expression is better to use in order to have fewer fake alerts. Would be grateful for a hint.

Answer (score 2):

There's a neat trick to check Prometheus metric for constant growth/diminishment/whatever condition over a certain time interval.

Below we measure time fraction when TARGET_METRIC > 0 over last 8 hours with 5 minutes resolution.

```
avg_over_time( ( TARGET_METRIC > bool 0 )[8h:5m] )
```

There's **bool** operator modifier which return **1** if the condition is met and **0** otherwise. Hence, avg_over_time calculates average value of these 1's and 0's. If the condition was never met over this 8 hour long interval, we got an exact 0 as a result. If the condition was always met, we got an exact 1. And everything in between, if the condition was met sometimes.
Of course, it could be any condition and any metric including *functions* (!).

Now back to your example.
We need to check if the metric grows constantly over time. Let's use `deriv` function to check whether the metric increases, decreases or keeps the same value.

```
avg_over_time( ( deriv( artemis_message_count{job="activemq",queue=~".*"} ) > bool 0 )[8h:5m] ) == 1
```

Here we are. The condition above checks if `artemis_message_count{job="activemq",queue=~".*"}` increased over the last 8 hours with 5 minutes resolution.
If some deviation is acceptable then we replace "1" with "0.95" or something.